# Run Function on Invalid Fields (with jQuery Validation)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validation and I want to be able to run a function on each of the invalid fields of a form.  Here is what I am thinking:

```
jQuery(".jform").validate(
{
    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-inline",
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator)
    {
        jQuery(':input', this).each(function()
        {
            var ParentDiv = jQuery(Selector).parents(".control-group");
    ParentDiv.removeClass('error');

            if (!validator.valid(this))
            {
                ParentDiv.addClass('error');   
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I basically am trying to add a class to the div that contains any fields with errors.  The code above is not working - I think that I am missing something fundamental.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **highlight** callback instead of **invalidHandler**, this will get called for every invalid field.  You probably need to combine this with the unhighlight handler.

```
$(".jform").validate(
{
    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-inline",
    highlight: function(element, errorClass)
    {
       $(element).closest('div').addClass(errorClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass)
    {
       $(element).closest('div').removeClass(errorClass);
    }
});
```